# ROS Answers SE migration: learning ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Plz, can anybody help to start with ROS  the tutorials in ROS website took me no where

any suggestion for better start  off Tutorials

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41803/learning-ros/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-11**:
While at first site ROS might seem incomprehensible, only continued exposure can help you.

See this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/185205/what-are-publishers-and-subscribers/ does it help a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, it depends on what you are trying to do.

Do you have any ROS robots available to you? If so, I would suggest you try to map a room. If not, you can certainly do it with a pr2 in [gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BuildingAMapInSimulation).

If you are trying to code get example code, I would search through the repositories.

If you are like me, the only way to learn ROS is to do. The community is always available to answer questions, so don't hesitate to ask them!

Hope this was slightly useful to you.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4